# Systemcall multiprocess child not resuming in parent (fork) Linux

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork, system-calls

Tracing exec process from the parent to count the number of forks. In the parent I resume the execve and verify it stopped. I resume it (with ptrace(cont..)or SIGCONT). However its not resuming.

I read I should set `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC option` failing to do so results in SIGTRAP being sent to tracee upon a call to execve. Ive  added into the child & parent, it doesnt seem to make a difference.

Im using Linux MX, it shouldnt be a problem as this should work in all recent Linux versions.

argument: /bin/bash -c "echo 'first test' | wc -c"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status;
    int counter = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        exit(1);
    else if (pid == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, pid, NULL, NULL);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC);
        raise(SIGSTOP);
        execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL);
    } else {
        wait(&status);
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            printf("child is stopped");

        if (status == 0) 
            printf("The child process terminated normally.");
        if (status == 1)
            printf("The child process terminated with an error!.");


        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL); //<< Child should restart here, not sure if pid = childs or parents.
        raise(SIGCONT); // if ptrace(cont) doesnt work then this should make the child start.

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            printf("child is stopped"); // << this shouldnt print bc Ive continued the child process.

        while (1) {
            ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_EXITKILL | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK);

            if (status >> 8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK << 8)) {
                 printf("it works");
                 break;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `raise(SIGCONT)` raises a signal in the *calling* process.  Presumably, however, it is the child whom you want to receive the signal.  Use `kill()` for that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger wouldnt that kill the execve, making it unable for ptrace to trace the number of forks systemcalls?

Comment: `kill()` just sends the signal you specify to the process(es) you specify.  If you want the parent to send a `SIGCONT` to the child, as it seems you do, then that is how you would do it.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to expect the second `WIFSTOPPED()` to produce a different result than the first one does.  It will report on the state of the process as-of the return from the `wait()`, as encoded in `status`, which may well not be indicative of its state after the `ptrace()` and `raise()` (or `kill()`) calls.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Got it. I was thinking of  doing `ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_EXITKILL)`. would that work too? 
One last thing, should  I handle the forks in execve or they wont have any effect on my code when I use ptrace() to count the number of forks?

Comment: What would it mean to "handle the forks in execve"?  Do you mean "in the program started via execve"?  If so, how do you imagine you could do that?

Answer (score 2):

The question and some of the code comments indicate some uncertainty about the behavior of `ptrace`, that in turn suggests unfamiliarity with its [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html).  Manual pages are not always easy to understand, but you should definitely start there.

There are several problems with the program presented. Among the more significant are:

1. `PTRACE_TRACEME` is the only ptrace command recognized from the tracee.  All other ptrace commands must be executed by the trac*er*, which is the parent in this case.  In particular, any `PTRACE_SETOPTIONS` commands must be executed by the tracer.
2. The tracer (parent) uses `raise()` to attempt to send a `SIGCONT` to the child.  This is wrong for two reasons:

   1. `raise()` sends the specified signal to the *calling* process, which is not the one that is intended to receive the signal.  The `kill()` function should be used instead to send a signal (of your choice) to another process.  But,
   2. A traced process is stopped whenever it receives a signal, but this ptrace-stop is different from "stopped by a signal".  The effect of `SIGCONT` to resume execution applies only to the latter kind of stoppage.  Therefore, sending a ptrace-stopped process a `SIGCONT` is counterproductive if the objective is to make the tracee resume execution.  Not only will it not resume the process from ptrace-stop, but when it ultimately is delivered, it will cause the process to reenter ptrace-stop.
3. The program seems to assume that the second `WIFSTOPPED(status)` might evaluate to a different value than the first, and in particular, to a value that reflects the child's status at the time of the evaluation of `WIFSTOPPED`.  That is a faulty assumption.  `WIFSTOPPED` and its brethren simply interpret the status integer provided by `wait()`, which is a static representation of the status of the waited-for process as of the time the `wait` returned.  It will not reflect any status changes since that time.
4. The program pervasively assumes that all its function calls succeed normally.  Generally speaking, this is not a safe assumption.  The program should check the return values of its function calls to verify successful completion, and take appropriate action (error message, possibly program termination) in the event of unexpected failure.

Overall, the program does not reflect a good understanding about the usage paradigm of `ptrace()`, and especially about the role of signals.  For example, I take this comment:

> I read I should set `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC option` failing to do so results
> in SIGTRAP being sent to tracee upon a call to execve.

Yes, if the `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` is not enabled, then the traced process will be sent a `SIGTRAP` when it calls `execve`, but the whole point of that is so that the tracer can *catch* that and have the option to trace the tracee at that point.  As with any signal (other than `SIGKILL`) delivered to the tracee, the tracer has complete control over whether the signal is actually acted upon by the tracee.  Furthermore, if `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` is in effect then the tracee *still* stops for tracing when it performs an `execve` -- the difference is that the status returned to the tracer can distinguish between this case and the one where a `SIGTRAP` is delivered to the tracee for some other reason (read the docs for details).

So here's a general outline:

- The original process `fork`s.
- The child executes a `PTRACE_TRACEME` command to attach itself as tracee to its parent process.  (It is not useful for your purposes for the child to execute any other `ptrace` commands.)
- The child proceeds normally to whichever `exec`-family function is appropriate (all will eventually result in a call to `execve`).  It's not particularly useful for the child to send itself a signal prior to the exec if the only point is to get the attention of the tracer.
- The parent loops, repeatedly `wait`ing for the child.  It doesn't have to use the `wait()` function specifically; other functions from that family, such as `waitpid()`, may also be used.
- Upon each successful return from a `wait`, the parent handles a ptrace or other event. The first of these is likely to be the `SIGTRAP` generated by the child's initial `execve` (though it cannot be ruled out that another event, for a different signal, is received first).  The status code filled in by `wait` conveys information about the nature of the event, and in particular, which signal or traced event triggered it.
- The parent sets whatever ptrace options it wants when the first ptrace event is received.  This can include `PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC` if you like, though again, exec events are traced regardless.  If you want to count not only the forks of the initial child, but also any forks of that child's descendants, then you probably want to set `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`.
- After every event handled, the parent performs a `PTRACE_CONT` command targeting the tracee.  If you are tracing all the forked descendants, then the applicable tracee is not necessarily the initial child.
- The parent exits the loop after it has handled a termination event for every traced descendant.